# Receiving an error message while using Tkinter with SQLite, 'probably unsupported type.'

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

This is a table I have created within my SQLite database called 'RawMaterials'. This code is directly above the following Class.

```
self.c.execute("""CREATE TABLE RawMaterials (
        date integer,
        po integer,
        stock integer,
        batch integer,
        recieved integer,
        test text,
        result text,
        comment text
        )""")
```

My below class uses a dictionary and a for loop to create several entries for a Tkinter app. The following method def submit(self): is attempting to retrieve the information placed into those entries and input the information into a sqlite database table as shown above. This however is not working, im not sure why or how to get around this obstacle.

```
class RawMaterials:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('qualitycontrol.db')
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()

self.entry_dict = {'Date': {'master' : self.myFrame, 'column' : 1, 'row' : 0},
                       'PO Number': {'master' : self.myFrame, 'column' : 1, 'row' : 1},
                       'stock Code': {'master' : self.myFrame, 'column' : 1, 'row' : 2},
                       'Batch': {'master' : self.myFrame, 'column' : 1, 'row' : 3},
                       'Sample Recieved': {'master' : self.myFrame, 'column' : 1, 'row' : 4},
                       'Test': {'master' : self.myFrame, 'column' : 1, 'row' : 5},
                       'Result': {'master' : self.myFrame, 'column' : 1, 'row' : 6},
                       'Comments': {'master' : self.myFrame, 'column' : 1, 'row' : 7}}
        for entries, info in self.entry_dict.items():
            entries = tk.Entry(master=info['master'], relief=GROOVE)
            entries.grid(row=info['row'], column=info['column'], padx=10, pady=5)

 self.submitButton = tk.Button(self.myFrame, text=("Submit"), relief=GROOVE, command = 
 self.submit, width=30)
 self.submitButton.grid(row=8, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, columnspan=2)

     def submit(self):
        # INSERT ENTRY FIELDS TO DB TABLE
          self.c.execute("INSERT INTO RawMaterials VALUES (:date, :po, :stock, :batch, 
          :recieved, :test, :result, :comment)",
            {
                'date': self.entry_dict.get('Date'),
                'po': self.entry_dict.get('PO Number'),
                'stock': self.entry_dict.get('stock Code'),
                'batch': self.entry_dict.get('Batch'),
                'recieved': self.entry_dict.get('Sample Recieved'),
                'test': self.entry_dict.get('Test'),
                'result': self.entry_dict.get('Result'),
                'comment': self.entry_dict.get('Comments'),
            })

        # COMMIT AND CLOSE DB CONNECTION
        self.conn.commit()
        self.conn.close()
```

This is the error I am receiving upon running this code, filling in the entries and hitting the submit Button tied to the submit method:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program 
Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0
\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\leonhill\Desktop\sqlite\app.py", line 80, in submit
    self.c.execute("INSERT INTO RawMaterials VALUES (:date, :po, :stock, :batch, :recieved, 
:test, :result, :comment)",
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter :date - probably unsupported type.
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to print out the content of those `self.entry_dict.get(...)` and you will see what is wrong.

Comment: @acw1668 Ahh it prints the contents of the dictionary, rather than the contents of the entry. That has given me a clearer picture. Thanks. However, would you know what direction I'm to go in to get the contents of the entries? Much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overwrite the values of `self.entry_dict` with the created `Entry` widgets:

```
def __init__(self, master):
    ...
    for field, info in self.entry_dict.items():
        entry = tk.Entry(master=info['master'], relief=tk.GROOVE)
        entry.grid(row=info['row'], column=info['column'], padx=10, pady=5)
        self.entry_dict[field] = entry  # replace the dict by entry
    ...
```

Then you need to update `submit()` to call `get()` on those `Entry` widgets:

```py
def submit(self):
    # INSERT ENTRY FIELDS TO DB TABLE
    self.c.execute("INSERT INTO RawMaterials VALUES (:date, :po, :stock, :batch, :recieved, :test, :result, :comment)",
        {
            'date': self.entry_dict['Date'].get(),
            'po': self.entry_dict['PO Number'].get(),
            'stock': self.entry_dict['stock Code'].get(),
            'batch': self.entry_dict['Batch'].get(),
            'recieved': self.entry_dict['Sample Recieved'].get(),
            'test': self.entry_dict['Test'].get(),
            'result': self.entry_dict['Result'].get(),
            'comment': self.entry_dict['Comments'].get(),
        })

    # COMMIT AND CLOSE DB CONNECTION
    self.conn.commit()
    self.conn.close()
```

Note that if you don't want to overwrite `self.entry_dict`, you need to create another `dict` to store those `Entry` widgets.

Comment: That worked, thank you. To help me understand, stating 'self.entry_dict[field] = entry' in the class, then stating ''date': self.entry_dict['Date'].get()' in the method will help link the two? making the program take the information entered? I hope that makes sense, it worked anyway so thank you!